# How to check if a value exists already in a Firebase and get key in android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

In my android application, when the user logs in, I need to check my realtime database to determine if the users ID exists within this database. Once the users ID has been located, i then need to retrieve the parent node of this ID in order to determine if the user logging in is a customer or employee. I'm having some difficulties coding this, as i'm relatively new to using firebase.

Here is my code so far:

```
final String user_id = Objects.requireNonNull(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            if(ds.child(user_id).exists())
            {
                //check if employee or customer?
                String cust_or_emp =  ds.child(user_id).getKey();
                Log.d("test1",String.valueOf(ds.child(user_id).getKey()));
                if (cust_or_emp.equals("Customers"))
                {
                            name= Objects.requireNonNull(ds.child(user_id).child("User_Information").child("firstName").getValue()).toString();
                            Log.e("first name is ", "firstname :" + name);
                            toNextActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                            toNextActivity.putExtra("name",name);
                            Log.e("2first name is ", "firstname :" + name);
                            progressBarLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).startActivity(toNextActivity);
                            getActivity().finish();
                } else if (cust_or_emp.equals("Employee")) {
                    //code for if the key is employee
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
    {
        Log.d("error", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

[image: database model]

Currently when I run my application, nothing appears to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching a value listener to the root of your database. Then in your `onDataChange` you loop over the child node, which means that your `ds` snapshot is for the `Users` node, while you seem to think it's for the `Employee` and `Customers` node.

The fix should be to listen to the `Users` node instead:

```
rootRef.child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

---

Your current approach is highly inefficient, as (even when you fix the above) you're loading the entire `Users` node to check if a specific user exists in there. As you add more users to the app, this means you're loading more and more data, without using it.

A better approach is to check whether the specific user exists under each specific node:

```
rootRef.child("Users/Employee").child(user_id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            ... handle the Employee
        }
        else {
            rootRef.child("Users/Customer").child(user_id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        ... handle the Customer
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```